# AEM Author instance corrupted

Tags: aem

My AEM 6.2 instance showing weird issue from 2-3 days. Now, it is not showing Login page and once I login through crx/de many other functionality(like allowing components are not showing while adding new component) on different pages are not working. Also, while creating new segment, drop down is not filled with default values. So it seems that my instance got corrupted somehow. Can anyone suggest how to recover corrupted instance and how to avoid such issue in future.

**Update:**
When I updated the Journal.log file present at path crx-quickstart/repository/segmentstore by removing few last entries, it again started working perfectly with a version of old data(few days old). Here my assumption is Journal.log records the database(tar) used by AEM). So, now my question is-- Is it a good way to recover the instance? In log, I was not able to find any specific entries showing the reason of this weird issue.

Comment: You should check if the OSGi bundles are active and check the logs to get an idea what is going on.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic, I have updated my question with latest findings. In log, I was not able to find any specific entries showing the reason of this weird issue.

Comment: No, the instance should not be recovered by editing the Journal file. You should automate content backups and deployments in my opinion. Working on a file system level can easily break a lot of things if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I am new to AEM and not sure which kind of record Journal file holds. But once I removed few last record from Journal file, my instance got recovered. I was just playing around my environment to recover it after having a backup.

Comment: Maybe the following presentation helps you a little, if you have to remove corrupt content in a more fine grained way. This is from the TarMK lead developer of Oak (and even the former Jackrabbit times).  https://adapt.to/2016/en/schedule/into-the-tar-pit--a-tarmk-deep-dive.html.      And of course, this is just a chance. Backup/Restore should be your safety net.

Answer (score 0):

In the `crx-quickstart` folder

1. delete the index folder `(crx-quickstart/repository/index)`
2. restart

Comment: I can't see any impact of deleting index folder.